# Change string format column date into dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: python

I have a column which contains data on this format (a string, essentially):

```
21 apr 2015
```

I need to parse this column, which contains several items, and output to date format, like:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

In python, I have seen many examples, but it always deals with a "sort of" formatted date, these are really not formatted, as You can see, so how could achieve that?

I can't use `pandas` though.

I have seen examples like this:

```
string_date = "2013-09-28 20:30:55.78200"
datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

But, this deals with a string, which has "some" format.

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that returns the correct format you need using strptime
and strftime for formatting

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert_csv_date(csv_date):
  return datetime.strptime(csv_date, "%d %b %Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

csv_date="21 apr 2015"
In [492]: convert_csv_date(csv_date)                                                                                                                          
Out[492]: '21/04/2015'
```

UPDATE: Here is a full program that writes data to a csv file in the format of your dates, then uses convert_csv_date to update the data and write a new file to compare with. I hope this helps ( you may have to change the file directory name, i used /tmp):

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

def convert_csv_date(csv_date):
  return datetime.strptime(csv_date, "%d %b %Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")


lines = [['Vacation_Days', 'Date'],
 ['New Years', '01 jan 2019'],
 ['Labor Day', '02 sep 2019'],
 ['Thanksgiving', '24 nov 2019']]

with open('/tmp/output.csv', 'w') as writer:
    fd = csv.writer(writer)
    fd.writerows(lines)

r = csv.reader(open('/tmp/output.csv')) # Here's a sample date csv file
lines = list(r)

for item in lines[1:]: 
   item[1] = convert_csv_date(str(item[1])) 

print(lines)

with open('/tmp/output_test.csv', 'w') as writer:
    fd = csv.writer(writer)
    fd.writerows(lines)
```

Comment: Hi, thank You, this seems to be more appropriate for my situation, just one question, what if I have a column containing some dates on that format, is it really difficult to modify in that case?

Comment: So some columns already have that format? If they only have those two formats, you can use try/except block because in a fail situation, you just return the csv_date in the except column, do you want me to write a second solution for that one? Let me know a case example and i'll add an update for it to my answer

Comment: Hi, yes, I have a column on a csv file, it has many items, all of them with that format '22 aug 1999', for example, so, I need to read and output that column with the 'dd/mm/yyyy' format, is that not so difficult to modify on your solution? Thank You very much!

Comment: I'll update it here soon with that, i'll make a csv with three columns and write it to iterate and update the date column. Let me know if thats what your looking for. How do you read your csv btw without pandas, are you manually parsing it?

Comment: Yes, I'm just using csv package, yes, that sounds like what I'm looking for :-))), wow, loking forward, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, this does gives me an idea, but I need to parse a csv column, so, I'm gonna try and maybe open a new question for it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the `datetime` library, you may handle this in two steps.  First, call `strptime` to convert your input text date `21 apr 2015` to a bona fide Python `datetime`.  Then, to generate another date string in the format `%d/%m/%Y`, call `strftime`:

```
inp = "21 apr 2015"
out = datetime.strptime(inp, "%d %b %Y")
print(out.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

This prints:

```
21/04/2015
```